# How to access c# variables from a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a C# file that pulls various config settings from different config files. A JavaScript application I'm writing needs some of those settings to run. I'm having trouble bringing the C# variables into the js file. Not sure what is the best approach. They need to end up as a JS object on the page. Would adding them to a JSon object in the C# file & calling that from the JS file work? Not even sure how to do that to be honest. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's the type of that application?

Comment: What is your application? Is it a MVC WebApplication? Does the javascript file reside in the same application?

Comment: Sorry should have said. It's MVC.

Comment: JS is also on the same application

Answer (score 3):

You can just declare a global variable in one of your root pages (say, `_layout.cshtml`):

```html
<script>
    var settings = {
        foo: @(IsFoo ? "true", "false"),
        bar: @SomeNumber,
        baz: "@ImportantString"
    }
</script>
```

Or, if you're writing a Web API, you can just add a `/settings` endpoint you can query like so (Assuming you're using jQuery):

```
$.get("/settings", response => {
    // Store the `response` in a global variable.
});
```

Comment: Why are you assuming this is an MVC application? What if the C# aplication is a Web API and the javascript is in another frontend application (e.g Angular app)?

Comment: @Alisson: If the OP were writing an Web API, the obvious answer (add a `/settings` call) would probably have been obvious enough to the OP. _"They need to end up as a JS object on the page."_ makes me think the OP is implying he has C# available on those pages.

Comment: I agree that it could be obvious for us, but I'm not sure it'd be to OP as well, maybe adding a `/settings` is exactly what they need.

Comment: I've added an extra option, @Alisson. Oh look, OP just said he's using MVC.

Answer (score -1):

If it's an independent javascript project and .net is more of an API, you need to make an API call which will send you those config settings.

If your javascript is part of .net MVC application, i.e., you are adding your javascript through an  tag at then end of a .cshtml/.aspx file, you can easily pass it through a global variable, but even then the C# code need to pass those values through Modal to the .cshtml/aspx file.

what you can do is:

```
var pageConfig = pageConfig || {};
pageconfig.settings = @Html.Raw(Model.Settings); // This model object is part of the C# code and my assumption is that Settings will have array of configurations.
```

This can also be done globally, depending upon how the C# code is written.

Comment: There are many different data types for which `@Html.Raw(Model.Settings);` is not going to work...

Comment: I apologize for not being clear, the Settings is actually a json Serialized string having the data required.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that when you say 'various config settings' you're referring to .NET's `ApplicationSettings` (defined in Visual Studio's Properties > Settings), we've done something similar, in a generic manner, as follows:

```
public void WriteSettings(TextWriter writer) 
{
    // Declare the nameSpace for the DLL you want to pull settings from
    var nameSpace = "foo.Bar"
    ApplicationSettingsBase properties = (System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase)Activator.CreateInstance(nameSpace, string.Format("{0}.Properties.Settings", nameSpace)).Unwrap();
    foreach (SettingsProperty property in properties.Properties) 
    {
        writer.Write(string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\", property.Name, properties[property.Name]);
    }
}
```

I've ignored a few issues in your case:

- I've not bothered trying to deal with non-strings; consider looking at `property.PropertyType` and casting your values appropriately
- I've wrapped this in a function that accepts a `TextWriter`; you can pass this method `Response.Output`